# automatically generate API controllers in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an existing SQL Server database that I want to use in a ASP.NET Core 3.0 web API project using Visual Studio 2019.

I'm following this tutorial to help me figure out how to do this:
[Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

I don't need any views, because I'm going to have a separate ReactJS project for my front-end views that the user will interact with in a browser. I just want to use this API so that the ReactJS part can connect to it when it needs to

I have the solution created, but I'm not sure how to get Visual Studio to automatically generate the controllers from the database for what the tutorial calls CRUD.

I installed the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package using the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio.

Is there a special command I need to run or do I need to install a library?

Thanks!

Comment: From the context menu in the Solution Explorer: select a folder, click 'Add' and then 'New Scaffolded Item...' and select the appropriate 'Api Controller ...' option. If you don't see the option, I have the following two packages installed: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`. Depending on the option, you may need both.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Hi Ruard, that was it.  I was missing those 2 packaged.   Thanks!